# Django - make ModelForm (of an ImageField) accept only certain types of images

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I am using Pillow 2.3.0 with Django and I have an ImageField in my models.py like so:

```
class UserImages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

and I have a form like so:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImages
        fields = ['photo']
```

How do I make it so that the UploadImageForm only accepts png's and jpeg's? What I tried is adding this clean method to the form:

```
def clean_photo(self):
    photo = self.cleaned_data.get('photo', False)
    if photo:
        fileType = photo.content_type
        if fileType in settings.VALID_IMAGE_FILETYPES: #png and jpeg
            return photo
    raise forms.ValidationError('FileType not supported: only upload jpegs and pngs.')
```

but according to this documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects) it says that "You'll still need to validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims – 'trust but verify'." How do I verify that the user did infact upload the file type which he claimed to upload?

Comment: If I were at your situation, I'd probably split the name of the file using the dot, something like `extension = file_name.split('.')[-1]` this will get you the extension of the file, and if that extension is not in your `VALID_IMAGE_FILETYPES` you can raise the error you need

Comment: @Liarez right, but according to the documentation which I linked to (I edited the link) it says that "You'll still need to validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims – 'trust but verify.'" How do I validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims?

Comment: you can use `PIL` to validate that the file is really an image using `Image.open(filepath)`, if the file is not an image, that line fails (you should insert it in a try-except) [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). There is more ways to check if the file is an Image, you can google it, this is just my suggestion. You're using Django ImageField not FileField, I think Django automatically check that file is an Image

Comment: Yes, I've checked `ImageField` and it already uses PIL to check the format of the image, if the image is not a known format for PIL it will fail automatically, check here: [Django ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield)

Comment: @Liarez ah, so it already checks if it is an Image recognized by PIL or not and if it is not a known format, then it returns an error which can be accessed by 'form.errors' in the template (assuming the UploadImageForm is passed to the template as the variable 'form')?

Comment: I think if PIL doesn't recognize the format of the image Django fails. I think it will be better for you to control that situation in your `def clean_photo`

Comment: @Liarez right, plus, I don't want to have to wait to upload to the file to the database until Django finds out that it cannot recognize the format. So going back to what was mentioned in the Django documentation (You'll still need to validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims), how will I be able to 'validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims' in my clean_photo function, after checking the content_type and the file extension?

Comment: If you add the `def clean_photo` it will check if the photo format is OK when the user try to submit the form (when the user click the submit button), if you add the def_clean you won't wait until the image is uploaded, Django check the Image when the form is validated. But the def clean_image has to be in your form, not in the model. With the clean_image if the file format is not known by PIL (meaning if the file is not jpeg, bmp, png...) the form will raise an error before the image is uploaded

Comment: @Liarez hm okay one sec, you lost me.. how will I be able to 'validate that the file contains the content that the content-type header claims' in my clean_photo function, after checking the file extension and checking that photo.content_type is in settings.VALID_IMAGE_FILETYPES? Because in my clean_photo function above, I'm not checking if the file format is known by PIL.. how do I check that in the clean_photo function?

Comment: mmmm maybe the problem is me, you want to do 2 checks of the file, the extension and the content ? If you want to do this 2 checks, you can do both in the `def clean_photo`. First I would recommend to do the check of the file format using the name, and the content of the file is checked by `PIL` automatically. I think I'm missing something here, sorry for the missunderstanding

Comment: @Liarez perfect, thanks.. I thought that by overriding the photo_clean method, PIL will not automatically check the content of the file but turns out, it does check the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ImageField` validators already verify that the uploaded file is a valid image file supported by Pillow. This is enough to prevent any malicious code injection - the worst that can happen is that someone uploads a file with a different extension than its file format.

I generally don't verify if an uploaded image is indeed the format it portraits to be. As long as it is a valid image file, and the file extension is in my allowed extension, I accept the uploaded file.

You can, however, easily override the `clean_photo` method to determine and verify the actual file type:

```
from django.utils.image import Image

def clean_photo(self):
    photo = self.cleaned_data.get(['photo'])
    if photo:
        format = Image.open(photo.file).format
        photo.file.seek(0)
        if format in settings.VALID_IMAGE_FILETYPES:
            return photo
    raise forms.ValidationError(...)
```

The `photo.file.seek(0)` part is important, without it you will run into problems when saving the file!!

Note that `format` is not necessarily equal to the content type or the extension: in the case of `.png` it is `'PNG'`, and in the case of `.jpg` it's `'JPEG'`. I don't know if other formats follow suit; you'll have to test that for yourself.

`Image.open` does not load the entire file content, just the header, so this method is quite fast. Using `timeit` and a random `.png` file, I've run the following code 1,000,000 times:

```
format = Image.open(g.photo).format
g.photo.seek(0)
```

The average time for this code was 0.0001 seconds, so yeah, lightning fast.

Comment: don't I need to close the file after opening it? shouldn't I do 'actualFile=Image.open(photo.file) format=actualFile.format actualFime.close()"?

Comment: @user2719875 If I understand it correctly, the `Image` object is merely a wrapper for a file-like object. The file-like object, `photo.file`, should not be closed as it is used later on; doing so would result in an error when saving the form. Django doesn't seem to close the `Image` object either.

Comment: At least for Django 1.8, `django.forms.ImageField` detects the real content type of the uploaded file for you, e.g., the `content_type` property of the field is the real MIME type. See `django/forms/fields.py:697`